# I can't rotate or pan but I can zoom

Tags: modeling, interface, customization, 3d-view

I have been having problems with blender recently where I will open a new project and all of a sudden I can rotate or pan.

I can still zoom and the issue usually just stops after I change views a couple of times, however today I opened a new file and the problem won't go away.

I am using a 3 button mouse, and these are my user preferences:

[image]

Comment: Try File->Load Factory Setings.  Or reinstall blender.

Comment: I tried Load factory settings and it still doesn't work

Comment: Ok so I did Load factory settings a couple times again and on the 5th or so try it worked, but its really sluggish and unresponsive.

Comment: I think it's a bug. I have had the same problem countless times and my only solution is relaunching, restarting or reinstalling.

Answer (score 3):

After exploring other options with view locking and having no results, I finally found a setting in my *User Preferences* under the *Interface* tab called *Auto Depth*.

Checking this seemed to allow me to pan and rotate again. I am not sure how it got unchecked, but if all else fails, might as well try before performing a reset.

(v2.78a)

Comment: this was also my problem in 2.83